# C# Problem with duplicate list entries

Tags: c#, arrays, split, duplicates

Hey guys i'm having a program and I am loading all lines inside a text box and split them from the char `:`

It works fine and all but it duplicates it. The output I get is:

```
ID: 1NAME: Stone
ID: 1NAME: Stone
ID: 2NAME: Grass
ID: 2NAME: Grass
ID: 3NAME: Dirt
ID: 3NAME: Dirt
```

When the output should be:

```
ID: 1NAME: Stone
ID: 2NAME: Grass
ID: 3NAME: Dirt
```

My code is:

```
    foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines("item.ids"))
    {
        items = line.Split(':');


        foreach (String part in items)
        {
            addToList(specs, "ID: "+line.Split(':').First() + "NAME: "+line.Split(':').Last() );
        }
    }
```

What am i Doing wrong?

Comment: please provide the addToList() and the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your second for each loop. It's not needed:

```
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines("item.ids"))
{
    items = line.Split(':');
    addToList(specs, "ID: "+line.Split(':').First() + "NAME: "+line.Split(':').Last() );

}
```

If you look at your code, your not using `part` but are looping the results from `Split(':')` which is giving you a string array of length 2.

Answer (score 4):

i think you need to loose the inner for each.
keep the call to addToList, though

```
// for every line in the file....
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines("item.ids"))
{
   //get the parts by splitting the line on the colon
   items = line.Split(':');

   //for every item in the parts (there are two parts, according to your code)
   // so this will loop twice--adding your item twice
   foreach (String part in items)
   {

     // you are splitting again, and this is not necessary
     // you could just call items.First() or items[0]
     // and items.Last() or items[1]
     addToList(specs, "ID: "+ line.Split(':').First() + 
                      "NAME: "+line.Split(':').Last() );
   }
 }
```

I would do something like this to fix it:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("item.ids"))
{
   items = line.Split(':');
   addToList(specs, "ID: "  + items.First() + 
                    "NAME: "+ items.Last() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that you do not have duplicate lines or entries on lines in the file you are reading in?

If you insert into a `HashSet<string>`, or run a LINQ Distinct() query on your existing list then you will avoid duplicates in the final result.